# retrieve value of one text view when there are many on ietm click listener

Tags: android

I have custom view defined for my list. There are 3 text fields in the custom view. On the item click listener i want to retrieve value of one of the text view. How can I do that?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code

```
mListviewObject.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            personId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personId);
            String val_personid = personId.getText().toString();                      

        }
    });
```

In this way you can chose whichever textview you want to refer

Comment: Thanks... dat helped!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**textView.getText().toString()** can be used to retrieve value

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.textview1:
            mTextview1.getText().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.textview2:
            mTextview2.getText().toString();

            break;

        case R.id.textview3:
            mTextview3.getText().toString();
            break;
   }
```

Comment: i know hot to get text from text view. But i'have three different text view in my custom view and i'm using that custom view in the list. Then how can i retrieve value of one of those text fields on item click listener??

Comment: If you show some code, it would be easier for everyone to answer :)

Comment: Like say I'm displaying id and name of persons in my list, then how can i get the value of only id on the item click listener?

Comment: in your xml, you have given id for each of your textview. In your intemClickListener, you can retriev the text based on that id like this: txtView1.findViewById(R.id.textview1)).getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

try this I used this code in my project :)

```
final View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
final String s = (String) ((TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

All Views have a findViewById(int id) method. You can find the smaller View within your custom View by using this method like so:

```
View customView;
customView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        View innerView = customView.findViewById(R.id.innerView);                   

    }
});
```

Then you will have a handle on your inner view.